# fetch one column from mysql prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have been doing some work with prepared statements as they are more secure, but in previous version of sql array fetching ($query->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)), it didn't allow to return one item from an array.

```
function getForumInfo( $id, $col ){
    global $mysqli, $db_table_prefix;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ? FROM forums WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $col, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($val);
    $out = $stmt->fetch()[$val];
    $stmt->close();
    return $out;
}
```

Something about that just looks off.

If I were to do the following:

```
echo getForumInfo( 7, 'name');
```

would it return JUST the value from column name, where id = 7?

Comment: `"SELECT (something) FROM tableName WHERE id = ?"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah, I bind that when I retrieve, my question is mostly about: $out = $stmt->fetch()[$val];

Comment: If row is not being provided by a user, then better make it `SELECT $row FROM forums WHERE id = ?` but your approach is really very cumbersome, and an example of what a code should **NEVER** be like

Comment: In actual prepared statement in mysql, this wouldn't be allowed (you can't put placeholders for identifiers, it would select a literal string `'columname'` for every matching record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The markers in prepared statements are not allowed for identifiers (such as table or column names), in the select list that names the columns to be returned by a `SELECT` statement, or to specify both operands of a binary operator such as the `=` sign. The latter restriction is necessary because it would be impossible to determine the parameter type. It's not allowed to compare marker with `NULL` by `? IS NULL` too. You should do something like:

```
function getForumInfo( $id, $col ){
    global $mysqli, $db_table_prefix;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT {$col} WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    // and so on...
```

---

Now, to your main question:

```
$out = $stmt->fetch()[$val];
```

would not yield your result. You have placed a `bind_result` call already; so simply use the following:

```
$stmt->bind_result($out);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
return $out;    // It could be `$val` if you use bind_result to $val
```

Comment: thanks for explaining the whole thing in depth a little more. I appreciate it.